# Help with tikzpicture for WBS (Work Breakdown structure)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

i need your help to boost my master thesis WBS

This is the code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=gray!60},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=gray!45,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=gray!30, text width=6.5em}
}
```

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
>=latex]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[draw=none]  {}
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
child {node[level 2] (c1) {Analyse} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c2) {Konzeption} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c3) {Umsetzung} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c4) {Abschluss} edge from parent[draw=none]};

% The second level, relatively positioned nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt] (c11) {Setting shape};
\node [below of = c11] (c12) {Choosing color};
\node [below of = c12] (c13) {Adding shading};

\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Using a Matrix};
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Relatively};
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {Absolutely};
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {Using overlays};

\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Default arrows};
\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Arrow library};
\node [below of = c32] (c33) {Resizing tips};
\node [below of = c33] (c34) {Shortening};
\node [below of = c34] (c35) {Bending};

\node [below of = c4, xshift=15pt] (c41) {Default arrows};
\node [below of = c41] (c42) {Arrow library};
\node [below of = c42] (c43) {Resizing tips};
\node [below of = c43] (c44) {Shortening};
\node [below of = c44] (c45) {Bending};
\end{scope}

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\foreach \value in {1,2,3}
\draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

%lines von Analyse zu Implementierung
\draw[->] (c1) |- (c2);
\draw[->] (c2) |- (c3);
\draw[->] (c3) |- (c4);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
\draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
\draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \label{fig:ustrategiepsp}
        \caption[Der Projektstrukturplan des Projektes]{Der Projektstrukturplan des Projekts}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

1. Question
   As you can see the Arrows  of the last rectangles are a bit smaller then the other ones. How can i solve this?
2. Question
   i Would like to edit the rectangles to look like shown in the picture: With a Start and End Date and a consecutive number. [image]

Thank you for all your Ideas and Help!

Answer (score 2):

First question is more or less easy. `Abschluss` node has no y,g,p like others, therefore it's not so high and `.195` anchor is different from other nodes. I suggest to add a `\strut` to make all of them equal in height.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=gray!60},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=gray!45,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=gray!30, text width=6.5em}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
>=latex]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[draw=none]  {}
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
child {node[level 2] (c1) {Analyse\strut} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c2) {Konzeption\strut} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c3) {Umsetzung\strut} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node[level 2] (c4) {Abschluss\strut} edge from parent[draw=none]};

% The second level, relatively positioned nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt] (c11) {Setting shape};
\node [below of = c11] (c12) {Choosing color};
\node [below of = c12] (c13) {Adding shading};

\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Using a Matrix};
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Relatively};
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {Absolutely};
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {Using overlays};

\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Default arrows};
\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Arrow library};
\node [below of = c32] (c33) {Resizing tips};
\node [below of = c33] (c34) {Shortening};
\node [below of = c34] (c35) {Bending};

\node [below of = c4, xshift=15pt] (c41) {Default arrows};
\node [below of = c41] (c42) {Arrow library};
\node [below of = c42] (c43) {Resizing tips};
\node [below of = c43] (c44) {Shortening};
\node [below of = c44] (c45) {Bending};
\end{scope}

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\foreach \value in {1,2,3}
\draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

%lines von Analyse zu Implementierung
\draw[->] (c1) |- (c2);
\draw[->] (c2) |- (c3);
\draw[->] (c3) |- (c4);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
\draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
\draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second question is not so easy to answer. I suggest to move to a new one.

But as a intial solution, if you previously know dimensions of the main part of the box, dates and number can be added as `labels`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dates/.style={draw, minimum width=15mm, minimum height=6mm, inner sep=1pt, draw, font=\small},
    start/.style={dates, anchor=north west, yshift=\pgflinewidth},
    end/.style={dates, anchor=north east, yshift=\pgflinewidth},
    number/.style={draw,minimum width=26mm, minimum height=7mm, rotate=90, anchor=south east,yshift=-\pgflinewidth}]
    
\node[minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm, label={[start]south west:12/12/22},
label={[end]south east:20/12/22},label={[number]north west:1.1}, draw]{Something};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am at a lecture for a few days. I will try it next week!